# Верно ли выделение одним тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"Новомодное веяние — *парение вейпов* стремительно набирает обороты в нынешние дни."

Comment: Эти вейпы (этих вейпов) кто-то парит, или они парят в воздухе? Может, "испускание паров" или "испарение ароматов"?

Comment: Это предложение - всё, что есть.

Comment: А следовало бы разобраться. Курение электронных сигарет — вдыхание паров. Vapor - пар, vaping — курение электронных сигарет. В России электронные сигареты называют вейпами, хотя в английском такого слова нет, а их курение — парением. По сути парение вейпов — плеоназм (парение парителей). Следовало бы говорить просто *вейпинг*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Новомодное веяние — парение вейпов стремительно набирает обороты в нынешние дни.**

> Второе тире опускается:
>   3)      если в подобной конструкции приложение предшествует определяемому слову, например: Самый лживый, лицемерный и самый влиятельный из всех «учителей жизни» – церковь, проповедуя «любовь к ближнему как к самому себе», в прошлом жгла десятки тысяч людей на кострах, благословляла «религиозные» войны (Горький); Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны – спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд (Из газет);
>   ([§93. Обособленные приложения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm))